# Summing common columns of multi table parent-child relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have four tables which are structured in a parent-child relation. One table has a primary key and the other three tables, otherwise unrelated to each other, have that primary key as a foreign key. That is, Table A has a primary key called customer ID. Tables B, C, and D also have customer ID and some other information.

What I want to achieve is to sum column2 of tables B, C, and D. I have tried:

```
SELECT dbo.a.primary_key,
       SUM(dbo.b.column2) AS Expr1,
       SUM(dbo.c.column2) AS Expr2, 
       SUM(dbo.d.column2) AS Expr3
FROM   dbo.a 
INNER JOIN dbo.b ON dbo.a.primary_key = dbo.b.column1 
INNER JOIN dbo.c ON dbo.a.primary_key = dbo.c.column1  
INNER JOIN dbo.d ON dbo.a.primary_key = dbo.d.column1
GROUP BY dbo.a.primary_key
```

This returns nothing. I have also tried a left outer join which returns nulls. I have also tried it with the below line, which is what I really want to achieve:

```
SUM(dbo.b.column2) + SUM(dbo.c.column2) + SUM(dbo.d.column2) AS Expr1
```

This may be down to poor design, as I could effectively join these three tables into one table, but believe it is tidier like this.

Once I have this problem solved, I would like to expand this as column3 of tables B, C, and D, so that they have a date field that is an int and links back to a date table (E). I would like to join tables A, B, C, and D to a newly created E at the same time, grouped by date and a.primary_key. Is this possible, or will I need to rethink the design?

Comment: How can you JOIN a Column `JOIN dbo.b.column2` to a table, shouldn't it be a table?

Comment: Once you get this one settled down, please make a nice example - as you did here - for the second part....perhaps in a new question!

Comment: sorry for the typo. I was too busy stripping down names of tables and columns and accidently changed that one. this still returns no results

Comment: If you change it to outer joins, do you get `primary_key` values coming back, and just no sums?

Comment: yes Andrew that is correct

Comment: @TSScoder May be it is because of `NULLS` in your `b.column2`. That can be fixed by replacing NULLS using `ISNULL(b.column2, 0)`.

Comment: @Andrew, shouldn't that be `sum(coalesce(dbo.b.column2,0))` ?

Comment: There is no null values in any of the tables

Comment: ok I think I have discovered what the problem is with your guys help. There was the possibility that a.primary_key did not contain a value in one or more of b.column1,c.column1 and d.column1

Comment: @Hellion, how embarrassing...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use APPLY instead of JOINs in case you just need to SELECT a single Column.
**EDIT**: If there are any `NULL` values this query should get you a `SUM`...
**EDIT2**: Changed the `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`, because in case one of the SUMS is non existent, the whole ROW will be dropped from the result.

```
SELECT a.primary_key,
    b.Sum AS Expr1,
    c.Sum AS Expr2, 
    d.Sum AS Expr3,
    ISNULL(b.Sum, 0) + ISNULL(c.Sum, 0) + ISNULL(d.Sum, 0) as [GrandTotal]
FROM dbo.Agency_Table a
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(b.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.b WHERE a.primary_key = b.column1) as b
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(c.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.c WHERE a.primary_key = c.column1) as c
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(d.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.d WHERE a.primary_key = d.column1) as d
```

Comment: this worked. as I posted above I think the problem was to do with this "ok I think I have discovered what the problem is with your guys help. There was the possibility that a.primary_key did not contain a value in one or more of b.column1,c.column1 and d.column1"

Comment: This should possibly be in a new question but what if I  wanted to change the top bit to b.sum + c.sum + d.sum this returns a null value. im guessing I need to catch the null values some way

Comment: @TSScoder I have posted a modified query that will also SELECT the sum of the three SUMs..

Answer (score 0):

The one clear thing from your example is that you accidentally put column names in your JOIN table names.

Change

```
INNER JOIN
dbo.b.column2
```

to

```
INNER JOIN
dbo.b
```

and the same for the other two.

Comment: sorry that was by mistake when removing column names. this still returns no results.

Comment: hmmmm.  There's nothing remarkable otherwise about your query.  Can you pull some sample data and post it here?  Ideally script it out as CREATE and INSERT statements so we can re-create the scenario.