# Summing common columns of multi table parent-child relation part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a direct follow on for [Summing common columns of multi table parent-child relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149150/summing-common-columns-of-multi-table-parent-child-relation?noredirect=1#comment31834140_21149150).

table layout is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a]

[primary_key] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[b]

[column1] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL
[column2] [int] NOT NULL
[column3] [int] not null

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[c]

[column1] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL
[column2] [int] NOT NULL
[column3] [int] not null

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[d]

[column1] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL
[column2] [int] NOT NULL
[column3] [int] not null

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTable]

[index] [int] NOT NULL
[date] [date] NOT NULL
```

This is roughly the design.   I had 1 parent and 3 children in the last query which I used this sql query to sum the 3 rows

```
SELECT a.primary_key,
b.Sum AS Expr1,
c.Sum AS Expr2, 
d.Sum AS Expr3,
ISNULL(b.Sum, 0) + ISNULL(c.Sum, 0) + ISNULL(d.Sum, 0) as [GrandTotal]
FROM dbo.Agency_Table a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(b.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.b WHERE a.primary_key = b.column1) as b
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(c.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.c WHERE a.primary_key = c.column1) as c
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(d.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.d WHERE a.primary_key = d.column1 as d
```

Now what I want to achieve is to use column 3 of b,c and d which is an int field which is linked to a date table (E). I want to group by dates. This can either be done by grouping on the int but preferably group by the actual date. so effectrively imagine the database as a mum and dad table that are not related and then its 3 kids.

what I envision is something like this

```
SELECT a.primary_key,
b.Sum AS Expr1,
c.Sum AS Expr2, 
d.Sum AS Expr3,
dbo.dateTable.Date 
ISNULL(b.Sum, 0) + ISNULL(c.Sum, 0) + ISNULL(d.Sum, 0) as [GrandTotal]
FROM dbo.Agency_Table a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(b.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.b WHERE a.primary_key = b.column1) as b
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(c.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.c WHERE a.primary_key = c.column1) as c
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(d.column2, 0)) [Sum] FROM dbo.d WHERE a.primary_key = d.column1 as d

//some kind of join to the next table
INNER JOIN dbo.b ON dbo.Date.index = dbo.b.Column3 
INNER JOIN dbo.c ON dbo.Date.index = dbo.c.column3  
INNER JOIN dbo.d ON dbo.Date.index = dbo.d.column3


group by dbo.dateTable.Date?
```

Sorry in advance I feel like im getting you to do my work.

This is for sql server 2012.

Comment: Tip: Some of us can read TSQL statements, e.g. CREATE TABLE, more easily than poetry. It would be a better way to describe your tables and their relations.

Comment: I do write some good poetry....modified as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine `b`, `c` and `d` with the UNION operator, adding in a column identifying the source table:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, 1 AS Src FROM dbo.b
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3, 2 AS Src FROM dbo.c
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3, 3 AS Src FROM dbo.d
```

...join the combined set to the relevant subset of `Date`:

```
  (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 1 AS Src FROM dbo.b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 2 AS Src FROM dbo.c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 3 AS Src FROM dbo.d
  ) AS s
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Dates AS d ON s.column3 = d.DateRef AND d.DateValue = ...
```

...then outer-join the result to `a`:

```
  (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 1 AS Src FROM dbo.b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 2 AS Src FROM dbo.c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 3 AS Src FROM dbo.d
  ) AS s
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Dates AS d ON s.column3 = d.DateRef AND d.DateValue = ...
RIGHT JOIN
  dbo.a AS a ON s.column1 = a.primary_key
```

Now you can group by `a.primary_key` and, in order to get separate aggregated results for each of the child tables, you can use CASE for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  a.primary_key,
  Expr1      = SUM(CASE s.Src WHEN 1 THEN s.column2),
  Expr2      = SUM(CASE s.Src WHEN 2 THEN s.column2),
  Expr3      = SUM(CASE s.Src WHEN 3 THEN s.column2),
  GrandTotal = SUM(s.column2)
FROM
  (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 1 AS Src FROM dbo.b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 2 AS Src FROM dbo.c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 3 AS Src FROM dbo.d
  ) AS s
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Dates AS d ON s.column3 = d.DateRef AND d.DateValue = ...
RIGHT JOIN
  dbo.a AS a ON s.column1 = a.primary_key
GROUP BY
  a.primary_key
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that by changing the where clause to include a filter on date it does allow me aq bit of flexibility to group them